# How to show $\int_M \text{div}_{M} ~F ~d\mu = \int_M \langle F, \nu \rangle H d\mu$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Assume $M$ is a compact convex manifold without boundary (I don't know what is necessary), smoothly embedded into $R^{n+1}$ by $F: S^n \rightarrow M \subset R^{n+1}$. Then how to show
$$
n(n+1) V_n = \int_M \text{div}_{M} ~F ~d\mu = \int_M \langle F, \nu \rangle  H d\mu
$$
where $\nu$ is outer unit normal of $M$ and $H$ is mean curvature. And
$$
V_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\int_M d\mu
$$
I think the first equal is the divergence theorem,  but I don't know  how to get the second equal.

Comment: $F$ is defined on the (sphere?) $S^n$, so what is $\operatorname{div}_M F$ as a function on $M$? (Is there any link, literature on the problem? Which is exactly the source for the problem?!)

Comment: @dan_fulea   it is from the equlity (7) of James A. McCoy's paper  "The mixed volume preserving mean curvature flow".